# Compliant JVM Error using executeExpression() in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am using AnyLogic 8 Professional 8.8.1.

When I try to use the function `executeExpression()` to run code that I have as a String, I get an error that I haven't encountered so far.

```
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
```

[image]

This error does not stop the simulation, And the function works.

I checked my JAVA version in the CMD window using `java -version` I get the following output:

```
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If anyone has an idea for a solution I would love to hear it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that your installed Java runtime environment is irrelevant (unless you have exported the model as standalone Java) since AnyLogic includes it's own Java environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has nothing to do with 8.8.1. Had same problem in 8.7.9.

This can be safely ignored but unfortunately not switched off. AnyLogic devs are aware and will turn the warning off in a future update. Until then, don't worry about it.

Ideally, you change your logic to call this function only once at the model start so you do not see the error all the time at runtime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Unfortunately, the function cannot be created only at the beginning, each agent has to create his own function (and they are different from each other) before he enters his station

Comment: Well, you can always change that. Do all those calls at the start and store them for later when the agent is created...